# RxRelay switches back to main thread after second accept call

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I'm using a popular library called [`RxRelay`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay).

```
private val refreshPlaylists = ReplayRelay.create<Unit>()

refreshPlaylists
    .map<Unit> { refresh ->
        Log.d("Activity", Thread.currentThread().name)
    }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe()

refreshPlaylists.accept(Unit)

relayCheck.setOnClickListener {
    refreshPlaylists.accept(Unit)
}
```

Output:

```
first accept: RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
onClickAccept: main
onClickAcceptSecond: main
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

The `OnClickListener` is called on the main thread, so `refreshPlaylists.accept(Unit)` is also called on the main thread.

The `subscribeOn()` operator has only effect on the subscription. Everything accepted afterwards will not regard this. Instead it will be emitted on the same thread as the call to `accept()`.

Use `observeOn()` instead to change the thread the emitted values are observed on.